# Open main window and close login (ruby)

Tags: ruby, ssh, shoes

I'm using Ruby Shoes.
I have a login window that upon entering username / password logs into remote server.

Upon completion I'd like to open new (main) window with some data. Thus, I need to:
1. open new window and close the login window
2. keep the ssh connection that login window opened

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: First it is important to know the version of Ruby you are working with. Secondly I would suggest to read about threads: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Thread.html